# Getting linker error between two .so files in linux

Tags: c++, linker-errors, netbeans-8

I have two .so files and I am trying to call a parameterized constructor from one .so to the other. And I am getting a linker error. Here is the piece of code.

ABC.h

```
class ABC
  {
     ABC();
     ABC(int i);
};
```

ABC.cpp

```
ABC::ABC()
{
   //do something
}
ABC::ABC(int i)
{
   //do something.
}
```

XYZ.cpp

```
#include "ABC.h"
void XYZ1()
{
    ABC abc();          // this passes
}
void XYZ1(int i)
{
    ABC abc(i);         // This results in linker error when I run XYZ's executable
}
void main()
{
    XYZ1();
}
```

Please note that I am using netbeans IDE.
I have noticed that parameterized constructor results in the error, default constructor doesn't throw any error. Is there any setting which I need to make am in the netbeans IDE.

Comment: Most-vexing parse will treat `ABC abc();` as a function declaration - declared, but not defined. Maybe the following `ABC abc(i);` is getting mixed up with that? Try to replace `ABC abc();` with `ABC abc;` or `ABC abc{};`. Not sure whether that will make it work, but worth a try.

Comment: Please post how you are compiling the code; and the actual code you are running (for instance, your `ABC.h` misses a `;`).

Comment: @Fureeish even having just a parameterized constructor without the default constructor results in linker error

Comment: How are you linking the code?

Comment: @Fureeish I am using LDLIBSOPTIONS option and I have mentioned the so name in the makefile.

Answer (score 1):

Your constructor is private, thus it can't be invoked

Answer (score 0):

I found out the problem, XYZ.so file was looking for ABC.so in the wrong location and thats the reason it was not able to link it properly. The reason why it was looking in some other location was because a path was set in "LD_LIBRARY_PATH", in this path a different version of ABC.so was present.

Thanks for your help.